# How to wrap 6 columns of col-3 on 2 rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Is it possible to make 6 col-3 columns wrap the last 3 onto a second row and have them centered?
Basically, I need a way to offset the first column by col-1.5

```
<div class="row mx-n2 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-lg-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="col-md-3">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Div 2</div> 
    <div class="col-md-3">Div 3</div> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="col-md-3">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Div 2</div> 
    <div class="col-md-3">Div 3</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to adding multiple `.rows` would be using a `.w-100` div that is only visible for large devices (`.d-none` for generally hiding it and `.d-lg-block`) for displaying it, resulting in breaking the line for large screens).

Combining this with `.justify-content-center` results in your desired behavior. A minimal working example is listed below:

```css
.col-6 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">3</div>
    <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">6</div>
</div>
```

Result for small devices:

[image: Result for small devices showing three rows with two columns]

Result for large devices:

[image: Result for large devices showing two rows with three columns that are centered]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in between:

```
 <div class="w-100"></div>
```

Like:

```
<div class="row mx-n2 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-lg-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

Check this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width

Answer (score 0):

- All you need is just use `justify-content-lg-center`.
- Bootstrap use 12 grid system so all column which expand that limit for example here, last three column will automatically goes to new row.

```css
div.col-lg-3 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```